# ClassCastException when using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, classcastexception

i'm starting at programming with andriod and I'm having some trouble with AsyncTask...

I've been reading about it but now I don't know what to do with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
        at reminder.app.Downloader$Receiver.doInBackground(Downloader.java:88)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

It seems it tries to cast something to Void[] in the internal process of executing that task.

Here is my code of AsyncTask:

```
private class Receiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        connect();
        if (_connected) receive();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {...}
}
```

I think recevie() and connect() methods have nothig to do with the error.

Anyway here is the code:

```
private void connect() {
    try {
        _socket = new Socket(_url, _port);
        _in = new Scanner(_socket.getInputStream());
        _out = new PrintWriter(_socket.getOutputStream());
        _connected = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _connected = false;
    }
}

public String recieve() {
    _response = "";
    try {
        _out.println("GET");
        _out.flush();
        while (!_in.hasNext()) ;
        _response = _in.nextLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _connected = false;
    }
}
```

Here where I call execute MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    downloader= new Downloader(_ADDRESS,_PORT,this,"");
    task = downloader.getReceiver();
    task.execute();
    ...
}

public AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> getReceiver(){
    return new Receiver();
}
```

I will apreciate anything you could tell me in order to improve! Thanks!

SOLVED!

Just I forget to declare properly the task variable:

```
AsyncTask task;
```

instead of:

```
AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> task;
```

Now I feel stupid XD

Comment: What does your `onBeforeExecute` look like?

Comment: What does your class declaration look like?

Comment: Whats your code to executing Asynctask?

Comment: Also please show how you start this task (ie, what you pass in the `execute` method).

Comment: AsyncTask declaration `extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` means that returning type of `doInBackground()` has to be the same as `Result` type. That might be the reason.

Comment: My class header looks like that:
private class Receiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {...}

And I'm calling it on the main thread with task.execute(); (task is a variable with an instance of Receiver).

I'm not overriden onBedoreExecute() method.

Comment: Please, post the code for `AsyncTask`.

Comment: What `receive()` does? Please, post all the relevant code.

Comment: Please post the code snippet that starts the AsyncTask.

Comment: @Joan Puicgerver What's the type of `task`?

Comment: AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>

Comment: @Joan Puicgerver Just tried your code, of course, without `Downloader`. It works, no exception. I believe the problem is in the class. Please, post relevant parts of it.

Comment: I realised the problem, I just noticed that my variable task was just a AsyncTask instead of a AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> and then there were problems casting!

Thanks Onik for that question that made me realise it and the others  to try to help me aswell!